# Embed and retrieve long string from image meta-data in Python

Tags: python, image, metadata

I would like to embed a single long string (several thousand characters) in the header of an image, and retrieve it later when reading the image, both using Python. I would like to be able to do this with PNG, TIFF, and JPEG formats. What is the easiest way to do this? (in particular I'm looking for a method with the easiest and fewest dependencies to install).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way with the fewest dependencies is to just use [exiftool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExifTool):

```
import subprocess as sub

def write_data(filename, data):
    cmd = ('exiftool', '-Comment=%s' % data, filename)
    sub.check_call(cmd)

def get_data(filename):
    cmd = ('exiftool', '-Comment', filename)
    return sub.check_output(cmd).split(':', 1)[-1].strip()

write_data('IMG_0001.jpg', 'a'*2048)
assert get_data('IMG_0001.jpg') == 'a'*2048
```

There are a few [considerations](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q10) that need to be taken into account depending on the type of data that you will be writing. Have a look at [pyexiv2](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/) and [gexiv2](http://redmine.yorba.org/projects/gexiv2/wiki) if you don't like using exiftool directly.